# How to edit an XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to edit a line in an XML file.  One of the XML elements, called polyline, contains coordinates:

```
<location>
  <street>Interstate 76 (Ohio to Valley Forge)</street>
  <direction>ONE_DIRECTION</direction>
  <location_description>Donegal, PA</location_description>
  <polyline>40.100045 -79.202435, 40.09966 -79.20235, 40.09938 -79.20231<polyline>
</location>
```

I need to reverse the order and add a comma between each coordinate so it is written as:

```
<polyline>-79.202435,40.100045,-79.20235,40.09966,-79.20231,40.09938<polyline>
```

I can parse the file and format the polyline element, but not sure how to write it back into the XML file:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
mydoc = minidom.parse(xmlFile)

items = mydoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline')
for item in items:
    newPolyline = []
    lineList = item.firstChild.data.split(",")
    for line in lineList:
        lon = line.split(" -")[1]
        lat = line.split(" -")[0]
        newPolyline.append(str(lon))
        newPolyline.append(str(lat))
```

Comment: Can you post the way you have tried?

Comment: I can parse, and format the line, but I'm not sure how to write the new line back to the XML file.

mydoc = minidom.parse(xmlFile)
items = mydoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline')
for item in items:
    newPolyline = []
    lineList = item.firstChild.data.split(",")
    for line in lineList:
        lon = line.split(" -")[1]
        lat = line.split(" -")[0]
        newPolyline.append(str(lon))
        newPolyline.append(str(lat))

Comment: There's lots of documentation on the internet for parsing xml with python. Have you done any research, and can you show what you've tried?

Comment: @J.Skinner: 1) the question is tagged "elementtree", but in the code you use minidom. Please clarify. 2) Please edit the question instead of putting code in comments, which is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code may look something like this:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

xmlobj = parseString('''<location>
    <street>Interstate 76 (Ohio to Valley Forge)</street>
    <direction>ONE_DIRECTION</direction>
    <location_description>Donegal, PA</location_description>
    <polyline>40.100045 -79.202435, 40.09966 -79.20235, 40.09938 -79.20231</polyline>
</location>''')

polyline = xmlobj.getElementsByTagName('polyline')[0].childNodes[0].data
xmlobj.getElementsByTagName('polyline')[0].childNodes[0].data = ','.join(
    ','.join(pair.split()[::-1]) for pair in polyline.split(','))
print(xmlobj.toxml())
```

This solution assumes, that there is only one `polyline` tag in the XML.